# Using Aggregation in Angular2-Meteor application

Tags: mongodb, angular, meteor, aggregation-framework, angular-meteor

Does anyone have an example of using aggregation framework inside angular 2. I have these two lines in my file.
export const ProductsMongo = new Mongo.Collection('products');
export const Products = new MongoObservable.Collection(ProductsMongo);

i use the first line for aggregation and the second for everything else. There must be a better way.

Thanks,

Comment: Aggregation is always a "server side" operation. You implement via meteor methods. There are many examples on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor+aggregation-framework

Comment: Yes but couldn't find a decent example of using aggregation and the second line i provided above Products = new MongoObservable.Collection(ProductsMongo); which is the angular2 way right?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about Mongo aggregation. Mongo aggregation is always done on server side so it has nothing to do with Angular. To use Mongo aggregation in Meteor, you could use this package: https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate